# Stacking Numpy Arrays repeatedly

Tags: arrays, numpy, stack, repeat

This might be an easy question, nevertheless I'm trying to get an answer ;)
I want to create a 3D numpy array, which is a repeated copy of another subarray, with a given number of copys.

In 1-D this is what I wanna do: a=[0,1,0], factor=3 leads to b=[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]

### My ideas so far:

-Creating the bigger array and slicing the subarray into it (is it possible to do that somehow itteratively inside the slice?).

-Building a list and using hstack, vstack and dstack.

```
for i in range(factor):
    array_list.append(data)
data=np.hstack(array_list)
for i in range(factor):
    array_list.append(data)
data=np.vstack(array_list)
for i in range(factor):
    array_list.append(data)
```

This works but seems not to be a nice and readable solution and even pretty memory hungry as the list has to be recreated after each stacking process. For me, the 3D case is interesting, but for the discussion it could be interesting to make that work even in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at `np.tile`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

For your simple 1d example:

```
In [1]: a=[0,1,0]
In [3]: np.tile(a,3)
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Sometimes is just THAT easy;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((2,2))
b = np.dstack((a,a))

for i in range(1):
    b = np.dstack((b,a))
```

Comment: Oh, I did get your qustion wrong. I had the 3D array in mind.